# Slightly off-centered buttons

Tags: html, css

[image]

I need these buttons to be horizontally centered within their container..as you can see, they are floating to the left. That is because I have a float: left; attribute on them.

However, when I remove the float: left; attribute and apply text-align: center; to the container, this is what happens...

[image]

Almost centered, but not quite. What's the deal? Thanks! :)

The container's CSS:

```
    #navbar {
    background: #303030;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Each button's CSS:

```
        a.button {
        width: 16.3%;
        background: #4d4d4d;
        height: 50px;
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        max-width: 250px;
        padding-top: 12px;      
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 145%;
        transition-property: background, z-index, font-size, color;
        transition-duration: 0.35s;         
    }
```

The relevant HTML

```
    <div id ="navbar">
<a href="https://www.answers.legal" class="button"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> HOME</a>
<a href="https://www.answers.legal/questions" class="button"><i class="fa fa-question"></i> Q&A</a>
<a href="https://www.answers.legal/forums" class="button"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> FORUMS</a>
<a href="https://www.answers.legal/contact" class="button"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> CONTACT</a>
<a href="https://www.answers.legal/support" class="button"><i class="fa fa-life-ring"></i> SUPPORT</a>
<a href="https://www.answers.legal/about" class="button"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> ABOUT</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us more of your code. Also a jsfiddle would help

Comment: After further inspection, I noticed that it displays perfectly on Firefox but not centered on Chrome.. any reason for that?

Comment: By the way, this glitch is only happening at small resolutions, so if you want to replicate it, zoom in to 400-500% on Chrome or resize your window.

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML [*in the question*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Done.. didn't think it mattered since it's just container and buttons xP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The misalignment is probably due to a space character between each link. This is a common problem when using `display: inline-block;`. You can remove with a couple of methods.

Method 1:
Set a negative `letter-spacing`. This depends on font-family and font-size, so try a couple of different values.

```
#navbar {
    letter-spacing: -4px; 
}

a.button {
    letter-spacing: normal;
}
```

Method 2:
Remove any space/linebreaks between the links. This will of course make the code pretty unreadable.

```
<a href="https://www.answers.legal" class="button"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> HOME</a><a href="https://www.answers.legal/questions" class="button"><i class="fa fa-question"></i> Q&A</a><a href="https://www.answers.legal/forums" class="button"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> FORUMS</a><a href="https://www.answers.legal/contact" class="button"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> CONTACT</a><a href="https://www.answers.legal/support" class="button"><i class="fa fa-life-ring"></i> SUPPORT</a><a href="https://www.answers.legal/about" class="button"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> ABOUT</a>
```

Method 3:
Ommit the closing `</a>` for all links but the last. This is still valid HTML. An `<a>` element will automatically close when it's followed by another `<a>`.

```
<a href="https://www.answers.legal" class="button"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> HOME
<a href="https://www.answers.legal/questions" class="button"><i class="fa fa-question"></i> Q&A
<a href="https://www.answers.legal/forums" class="button"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> FORUMS
<a href="https://www.answers.legal/contact" class="button"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> CONTACT
<a href="https://www.answers.legal/support" class="button"><i class="fa fa-life-ring"></i> SUPPORT
<a href="https://www.answers.legal/about" class="button"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> ABOUT</a>
```

Comment: UNLIMITED THUMBS UP.

I should have known better... thank you... I simply removed the space characters between each button and *bloop* problem solved.

Comment: How come this doesn't happen in Firefox? Firefox is smart enough to remove the space or what??

Comment: I guess firefox is smart enough. Lets hope the other browsers follow suit.

Comment: Your simple answer actually fixed like every mysterious problem I was having with my website related to those buttons lol.. so thanks again! 

https://www.answers.legal